# Image jQuery Sliding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to make an image slidein on page load but it doesn't seem to work at all. The delay has no problem but the sliding effect doesn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
 $(".bgslide").one('load', function () {
  $(this).delay(1000).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 'linear', 2000);
  }).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) jQuery(this).load();
 });
});
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/cDYvh/

Answer (score 2):

The `slide` effect comes with jQuery UI which you didn't include: http://jsfiddle.net/cDYvh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use $.animate() to avoid including jQuery UI. For example, you could accomplish  your example with something like this:

```
$(this).animate({ left: 2000px });
```

Note: You'll probably need to apply position:absolute to the elements.  Other items can be animated as well, including color, opacity, etc.

[Animate Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957217/jquery-animate)